# Command Line data loader; is an .SDL needed for extract?

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I'm going through and creating the xml doc for an automated data loader extract. I put in the extractSOQL query and i'm wondering if i need a .sdl mapping? I just need the extract in a CSV in no specific order.

Also as a side question if i put sfdc.extractionRequestSize to a size greater than the amount of rows i know the query will return will there be an error, or is their a value i can put in to simply return whatever the query brings up.

Comment: No, you don't need an sdl. You need sdl only if you want to have names different than the api names. Other than that, for expressing, sdl is not a requirement. Extraction request size is not the number of rows it returns, it's basically the size of the batch

Comment: @Raj Every doc i see requires an sdl for extract?? How would i just have a .bat call on dataLoader to perform the extract of an SoQL statement like a standard extract request

Comment: What do you mean every doc, can you specify the doc types??. You can remove the sdl attribute from your build files and run the job. It will work, sdl for extraction is only if you want column names different

Comment: Every document from salesforce, IE dev guides and so on. They all state you need an SDL to define the operation and the query...how else would you call on dataloader from .bat?

Comment: I can get on a screenshare with you if you are ok and see or show how i do the extract.